# XML DataGrid Where Certain Nodes Are Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, data-binding, datagrid

I am attempting to bind an XML file to a DataGrid. I am only bind the the "Transactions". What I cannot figure out is how to bind **only data that has empty nodes**.  For example, the transaction that has "UserName" of "NSmith" does not have a value for "CustomerFirst".
I want only this child to be bound to the DataGrid

```
<Root>

<Header>
  <value1>0000000</value1>
  <value2>1</value2>
  <value3>100.00</value3>
</Header>

<Transactions>
  <Txn>
    <id></id>
    <UserName>BSmith</User>
    <CustomerFirst>Bob</CustomerFirst>
    ...
  </Txn>
  <Txn>
    <id></id>
    <UserName>NSmith</User>
    <CustomerFirst></CustomerFirst>
    ...
  </Txn>
</Transactions>

</Root>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
serverPath = Server.MapPath("App_Data/" + xmlFileName);
DataSet dsBillPay = new DataSet();
dsBillPay.ReadXml(serverPath);
dgBillPay.DataSource = dsBillPay.Tables[1];
dgBillPay.DataBind();
```

The .Tables[1] is selecting the "Transactions".
Now the question is selecting data that has empty nodes.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq-to-Xml to filter out elements that have all of their child-elements specified with values and include only those with missing data.

The following example retrieves users that have an empty element but allows AddressTwo to be empty.

```
string xmlText = @"<Root>
                    <Header>
                        <value1>0000000</value1>
                        <value2>1</value2>
                        <value3>100.00</value3>
                    </Header>

                    <Transactions>
                        <Txn>
                            <id>1</id>
                            <UserName>BSmith</UserName>
                            <CustomerFirst>Bob</CustomerFirst>
                        </Txn>
                        <Txn>
                            <id>2</id>
                            <UserName>NSmith</UserName>
                            <CustomerFirst></CustomerFirst>
                        </Txn>
                        <Txn>
                            <id></id>
                            <UserName>JSmith</UserName>
                            <CustomerFirst>James</CustomerFirst>
                        </Txn>
                        <Txn>
                            <id>4</id>
                            <UserName>KSmith</UserName>
                            <CustomerFirst>Kevin</CustomerFirst>
                            <AddressTwo></AddressTwo>
                        </Txn>
                    </Transactions>

                    </Root>";

var root = XElement.Parse(xmlText);

    var elementsThatCanBeEmpty = new HashSet<XName>
                                     {
                                         XName.Get("AddressTwo")
                                     };

    var transactionsWithoutCustomerFirst =
        from transactions in root.Elements(XName.Get("Transactions")).Elements()
        where transactions.Elements().Any
            (
                el =>
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Value) &&
                !elementsThatCanBeEmpty.Contains(el.Name)
            )
        select transactions;

foreach(var t in transactionsWithoutCustomerFirst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.Element(XName.Get("UserName")).Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, this XML file could possibly have more than just the CustomerFirst node empty. There are a total of 20 nodes within a "txn" that could be blank.  Then I had wanted to bind the "Txn" to the DataGrid.

Comment: Is there an easy way to say that if "UserName or CustomerFirst or CustomerLast" are NullOrEmpty, then this particular Txn will be in the DataGrid.

Comment: Can we exclude certain fields in the WHERE statement? We have AddressTwo that is not required that we dont want to check.

Comment: @Nick.  I updated the answer.  You should think of asking an question the same as giving a specification.  If you leave off requirements, they won't get met.  Your original sample data should have included an AddressTwo element and specified what you really wanted to filter.

Comment: Anyway I can output the entire TXN node that had a result? -- or the nodes for that result that were empty?

Comment: @Nick, `transactionsWithoutCustomerFirst` will be an enumerable of txn nodes with empty elements.